# Issue connecting to internet after proper wifi configuration

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, wpa

I recently purchased a USB wifi dongle for my raspberry pi 2 B and attempted to connect through the Wifi Networks Panel Item in Raspbain Jessie. After entering the key, nothing happened, so I decided to check the network configuration files in `/etc/network/interfaces` and `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`. Everything seemed to be configured properly.

interfaces file:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

wpa_supplicant:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
        ssid="CXSD1"
        key_mgmt=NONE
        wep_key0="MYWIFIKEY"
}
```

When I checked the connection on `ifconfig` i got an `innet6 addr`, which I'm assuming is a static IP:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:aa:f1:15  
          inet6 addr: fe80::b27a:4007:e151:7eea/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:600 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:600 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:49896 (48.7 KiB)  TX bytes:49896 (48.7 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:da:38:42:48:46  
          inet6 addr: fe80::ee15:adc7:776c:fe8a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:51 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

I've tried SSHing to the computer and even used the epiphany web browser but to no avail. As I am still a beginner at Linux I would appreciate any help at fixing this issue and understanding what is wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Those inet6 details are link-local IP **version 6** addresses and whilst I do use IPv6 myself that is not helpful to you here. Network configuration is a subject that comes up a lot here - so you may want to look over some of the other questions and answers here...!  Use the search box on the top-right of the page here (and do that on three successive days for the next week or so for a Winter Bash 2015 short term cosmetic bonus!)

Comment: Appreciate the help @SlySven. I've searched a plethora of websites and googled the hell out of wifi configuration for Raspian for the past two days, but I have yet to find the same issue I am experiencing. Nonetheless, I'm sure your explanation will aid me in my quest for the truth. Thanks a lot!

Comment: As @SlySven mentioned you do not have IP Allocated. This is unlikely to be the Pi. How is your local network setup? Have you tried an Ethernet connection?

Comment: @Milliways I have not tried ethernet because I don't have the proper cable, as I haven't had the need for it until now. As for my network, it is a typical Verizon network with a supplied Verizon router. I have been able to connect to it easily from many different devices. When I try to connect through the new panel feature on Raspbian my network's SSID shows up and I put in the correct key but then it doesn't do anything, and there no error messages or warnings.

Comment: I would be surprised if a modern Telco router is using `WEP encryption` as indicated by `wep_key0`

Comment: @Milliways The router is a few years old, but I am sure it uses WEP encryption. So Raspbain automatically detected the SSID, used right encryption type, and stored it properly. I cannot understand why on earth is could not be connecting.

Comment: Can you look over this [Verizon](https://www.verizon.com/support/residential/internet/fiosinternet/networking/setup/security/125521.htm) page - and check for your router device - even they recommend using WPA or WPA2...! If it IS using one of those then trying to use WEP is not going to be that productive!

Comment: @SlySven So it was using WEP. I did some research and found that the wifi dongle will not work properly with WEP. So I upgraded to WPA and it's working great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I found the solution for anyone who's encountering the same frustrating problem. If your router uses WEP encryption be sure to upgrade it to WPA/WPA2. Most Wifi USB adapters for pi do not work with WEP any longer.